# Java stream map of map of list

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an entity that looks like this:

```
public class Snippet {
    private Integer docId;
    private Integer page;
    private Payload payload;
}
```

The input data is a `List<Snippet>`

I need to create an index that allows us to iterate over docIds and pages and obtain the associated Snippet objects.

So a data structure like this:

`Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Snippet>>>`

I can use Java streams to get a Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Snippet>> - but this won't collect the list of Snippets at the end.

```
        List<Snippet> input = ....;
        input.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Snippet::getDocId, 
                    Collectors.toMap(Snippet::getPage, Function.identity())
                 )
        );
```

How can I do the collecting to get a List as the final map value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, `Collectors.groupingBy(..)` gets collector as 2nd argument. So, just use `Collectors.groupingBy(..)` as 2nd argument of `Collectors.groupingBy(..)`

```
input.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Snippet::getDocId,
                        Collectors.groupingBy(Snippet::getPage,
                                Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Thank you - seems so obvious now that I read it.  I think I got hung up on the need to collect into a map - but I guess the groupingBy collector creates a map itself.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative for your current or future consideration.  It uses the `computeIfAbsent` method of the [Map Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html).

- create the final content map.
- iterate thru the list of `Snippets`
- if the `DocId` is not present, create the entry with `DocId` as key. Then try and store the `page` and `Snippet`
- if the `page` is not present, create the entry with `page` as key. Then store the `Snippet` in the list.

Here is an example using records in place of classes.

```
record PayLoad(String getValue) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + getValue() + "]";
    }
}

record Snippet(int getDocId, int getPage,
        PayLoad getPayLoad) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{%s, %s, %s}", getDocId,
                getPage, getPayLoad);
    }
}
```

Create some data

```
List<Snippet> input =
        List.of(new Snippet(1, 1, new PayLoad("A")),
                new Snippet(1, 2, new PayLoad("B")),
                new Snippet(1, 3, new PayLoad("C")),
                new Snippet(2, 1, new PayLoad("D")),
                new Snippet(2, 2, new PayLoad("E")),
                new Snippet(2, 3, new PayLoad("F")));
```

Store the snippets

```
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, List<Snippet>>> map =
        new HashMap<>();

for (Snippet s : input) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(s.getDocId(), v -> new HashMap<>())
            .computeIfAbsent(s.getPage(),
                    v -> new ArrayList<>())
            .add(s);
}
```

Print them

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> {
    System.out.println(k);
    v.forEach((kk, vv) -> System.out
            .println("          " + kk + " -> " + vv));
});
```

prints

```
1
          1 -> [{1, 1, [A]}]
          2 -> [{1, 2, [B]}]
          3 -> [{1, 3, [C]}]
2
          1 -> [{2, 1, [D]}]
          2 -> [{2, 2, [E]}]
          3 -> [{2, 3, [F]}]
```

Comment: Minimum version of Java 17?

Comment: Not at all.  The records were just to simplify the example but were finalized in Java 16.  The map is Java 8 so the actual production run will work with Java 8+.

Comment: This is a very clever solution - thank you.  computeIfAbsent makes for some very elegant code for cases that are too complex for the stream operation.  Thank you for going above and beyond - it is appreciated.